# JavaScript - 2D Arrays / Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to create array and/ or objects to hold values for graphing. The data comes in as JSON. Each Object has an asset code a date and two measurements i am interested in. (measurement 3 with be the net of the two) I am attempting to filter by both an asset code and then the date the data was captured. I would like to compile this into a single object that I could loop through and extract data for each asset by date.  My attempt bellow was to create an array of arrays but have run into some undefined variable issues. Is there a more concise way to achieve this?

```
var response = []; //to store global variables

response.handle = function handle (resp) {
    response.measurment1 = {};
    response.measurmentt2 = {};
    response.measurement3 = {};

    var dateArray = [];
    var assetCodeArray = [];

    for(object in resp) {
        if (extend.contains(dateArray,resp[object].date == false){ // extend.contains is a function that checks if an obj is in an array
            dateArray.push(resp[object].date;
        }
        if (extend.contains(dateArray,resp[object].AssetCode == false){ // extend.contains is a function that checks if an obj is in an array
            assetCodeArray.push(resp[object].date;
        }
    }
    for (var code in assetCodeArray) {
        response.injObj[assetCodeArray[code]] = [];
        response.WthObj[assetCodeArray[code]] = [];
        response.netObj[assetCodeArray[code]] = [];

        var filteredRespAC = resp.filter(function(y) {
            return y.AssetCode == assetCodeArray[code];
        });
        var AssetCodeInj = 0;
        var AssetCodeWth = 0;
        var AssetCodeNet = 0;
        for (var obj in filteredRespAC) {
            for (date in dateArray) {
                var filterACDate = filteredRespAC.filter(function(z) {
                    return z.date == dateArray[date];
                });

                var volInj = filterACDate[date]["Measurement1"];
                var volWth = filterACDate[date]["measurment2"];
                var volNet = volInj + volWth;

                response.injObj[assetCodeArray[code]].push(volInj);
                response.WthObj[assetCodeArray[code]].push(volWth);
                response.netObj[assetCodeArray[code]].push(volNet); 
    }
}
```

---

A representation of JSON is as follows:

```
[
    { 
        "ID" : 12345,
        "AssetCode" : "AC1",
        "Measure1" : 12345,
        "Measure2"  : -1234,
        "Date" : "2016-01-14T00:00:00"
   },{
        "ID" : 12346,
        "AssetCode" : "AC1",
        "Measure1" : 6789,
        "Measure2"  : -678,
        "Date" : "2016-01-14T00:00:00"
   },{
        "ID" : 12347,
        "AssetCode" : "AC2",
        "Measure1" : 12345,
        "Measure2"  : -1234,
        "Date" : "2016-01-14T00:00:00"
   },{
        "ID" : 12348,
        "AssetCode" : "AC1",
        "Measure1" : 12345,
        "Measure2"  : -1234,
        "Date" : "2016-01-13T00:00:00"
   }
]
```

Comment: it will be great if you can post an example json object

Comment: edited the post to include  example JSON

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Is that a copy-paste error?

Comment: Yes it was a copy and paste error. Fixed post accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is at least part of what you want.

```
data.reduce(function (last, current, index, array) {
  if (last[current.AssetCode] == undefined) {
    console.log(last);
    last[current.AssetCode] = array.filter(function (value) {
      return current.AssetCode === value.AssetCode;
    });
    return last;
  }
  return last;
}, {});
```

This function turns your JSON (after fixing the curly braces) in to this.

```
{
  AC1: [{
  AssetCode: "AC1",
  Date: "2016-01-14T00:00:00",
  ID: 12345,
  Measure1: 12345,
  Measure2: -1234
}, {
  AssetCode: "AC1",
  Date: "2016-01-14T00:00:00",
  ID: 12346,
  Measure1: 6789,
  Measure2: -678
}, {
  AssetCode: "AC1",
  Date: "2016-01-13T00:00:00",
  ID: 12348,
  Measure1: 12345,
  Measure2: -1234
}],
  AC2: [{
  AssetCode: "AC2",
  Date: "2016-01-14T00:00:00",
  ID: 12347,
  Measure1: 12345,
  Measure2: -1234
}]
}
```

Comment: This is great, I was able to loop through and assign values as I needed too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what your code is trying to accomplish, but if all you want to do is loop through the objects in your JSON array, then this is much simpler:

```
<script>
    var json = '[ { "ID" : 12345, "AssetCode" : "AC1", "Measure1" : 12345, "Measure2" : -1234, "Date" :"2016-01-14T00:00:00" }, { "ID" : 12346, "AssetCode" : "AC1", "Measure1" : 6789, "Measure2"  : -678, "Date" :"2016-01-14T00:00:00" }, { "ID" : 12347, "AssetCode" : "AC2", "Measure1" : 12345, "Measure2"  : -1234, "Date" :"2016-01-14T00:00:00" }, { "ID" : 12348, "AssetCode" : "AC1", "Measure1" : 12345, "Measure2"  : -1234, "Date" :"2016-01-13T00:00:00" } ]';
    var response = JSON.parse(json);

    for(var i = 0, j = response.length; i < j; i++) {
        var object = response[i];
        console.log(object);
        var measure3 = object.Measure1 + object.Measure2;
        console.log(measure3);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: my goal is to accomplish exactly what you did there. However, I would like to graph some of the results. I would essential like to have Dates on the x-axis & measure on the y-axis, then display data series broken out by asset code. Thus, i am trying to parse the response JSON into either new objects or preferably arrays so that the data can be accessed at the time the graph is to be initialized. Since the data will change every day, the script needs to be able to dynamically sort through the JSON.